# Securing wordpress user uploads

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security, file-upload

I have membership website with a specific page per user with their own data. They can upload images to their own folder in wordpress uploads. There's a major security hole in this setup since anyone can fiddle with the url searching for other users images. I also don't have access to Apache .conf files. Currently the only form of *security* I have is generating long alfanumeric characters for the filename.
How can I keep uploaded member files only available to the user that uploaded them in the first place? My failed attempts at securing this are:

**1. Adding .htaccess to the uploads directory with:**

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|doc|xls|pdf|html|htm|xlsx|docx)$ http://disney.com/ [NC]
```

This is not secure enough since the user can still search for files inserting the url into `<img src="">`

**2. Moving wordpress uploads outside the webroot**

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$wp_upload = wp_upload_dir();
function my_upload_dir($wp_upload) {
    $wp_upload['basedir'] = '/usr/home/myhiddendir/';
    $wp_upload['baseurl'] = '../myhiddendir/';
    $wp_upload['subdir'] = '';
    $wp_upload['path'] = $wp_upload['basedir'] . $wp_upload['subdir'];
    $wp_upload['url']  = $wp_upload['baseurl'] . $wp_upload['subdir'];

    return $wp_upload;
}
```

Files are uploaded correctly via $wp_upload['basedir'] but wont allow me to show the images with $wp_upload['baseurl'].I either get:

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):

Comment: I said I don't have access to .conf files nor php.ini

Comment: As I said files are uploaded correctly into that path but I cannot retrieve them. The URL asignned to the media upload is wrong.